# Return row if joined table meets condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to return rows based on whether or not a joined table row exists.  Basically I want a simple select where a column is in 1 or 2 values. The presence of the joined row will tell me to query for (1) or (0,1) Here's what I am trying to do, but I don't think I can put the case as the value for IN.  How can I rewrite this to work?

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
  FULL OUTER JOIN service_fbas ON service_fbas.channel_id = orders.channel_id 
  WHERE orders.processed_by IN CASE 
                               WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM service_fbas WHERE service_fbas.channel_id = orders.channel_id) 
                               THEN (0) 
                               ELSE (1,0) 
                               END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orders.*
ROM orders
WHERE [not] exists (select 1 from service_fbas ON service_fbas.channel_id = orders.channel_id)
```

Will select all orders where service_fbas EXISTS. You can do the opposite with NOT EXISTS.

Now in case you need to display I would use something like below:

```
SELECT orders.*, case when service_fbas.channel_id is not null then '1' else '1,0') as new_column name
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN service_fbas ON service_fbas.channel_id = orders.channel_id)
```

I had to guess about what you are trying to achieve but the above examples I think will give you some good ideas and tools.

In any case please feel free to elaborate and I can refine the solution.

Ted.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I should elaborate.  I want to either `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders.processed_by IN (1);`   Or....  `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders.processed_by IN (0,1);`   What determines the `(1)` or `(0,1)` is the presence of a service_fbas record where `service_fbas.channel_id = orders.channel_id`

Comment: I think the second example is exactly what you want no?

Comment: Sorry I'm having syntax errors. I'm putting this into a rails scope. I'll need to play with it a bit. But it seems with the left join, aren't we only going to get records that join because the orders.channel_id = service_fbas.channel_id ??

Comment: the LEFT join will return all records from order and 1 or 0,1 from the service_fbas. If you want to diplays also service_fbas column just add SELECT orders.*, service_fbas.*, case ...

Comment: So what I need actually is to go through all orders and if the channel_id of an order matches a service_fbas.channel_id, then search in (1,0) else earch in (1). So maybe an outer join would work here? I'm not great with sql.

Comment: can you provide some sample data in order to assist you better please?